# iOS - securely persisting login

Tags: ios, objective-c, session, data-persistence

How do you not make a user login to the app every time they relaunch the app? I've been working on a project and I have come to the realization that I do not know what the best way is. Obviously storing their name and password is not secure. There is a sever component which issues bearer tokens. Is it best to just persist that?

Comment: Store the credentials in keychain instead?

Comment: Preferably store a token in keychain and refresh it before it expires or re-ask for credentials if it has expired.

Comment: Best is to generate a session key once user logins. When app quit, the session key is lost, forcing user to re-login

Comment: I think it is problematic asking the user to login every time the app is quit so im going to go with the storing token in keychain approach i think. thanks!